# Docker AUFS... underlying fs... optimization by mount option?

Tags: docker

So I understand that docker is using /var/lib/docker/ to store every container and images... right?

That means the only optimization that I can do to my container is to optimize the underlying fs that /var/lib/docker/ is sitting on?

In that sense, can I assume that I should be optimizing the mount options of my underlying system fs? e.g. ext4 noatime, noadirtime etc etc

Also, can i use a different mount per /var/lib/docker/folder?? Any limitations and optimization settings considerations for the underlying disk docker is sitting on?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather squash my images
https://github.com/jwilder/docker-squash

and prefer Debian, for example as said here

https://docker.cn/p/6-dockerfile-tips-official-images-en

extract

The main advantage of the Debian image is the smaller size – it clocks in at around 85.1 MB compared to around 200 MB for Ubuntu.